# Non-monotone evasive graph properties.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Are there examples of non monotone graph properties which are evasive?
Since AKR conjecture doesn't mention them, there should be.

There is this property: "Is the graph a spanning tree?"
Is this property evasive? Clearly it is not monotone. But it seems to be evasive since spanning tree is the output which adversary gives in case of  "Is the graph connected?" These two properties are thus related.

Is there a good example which is not related to some monotone property like in above case?

Is regularity evasive?

Comment: What do you mean by "evasive"? Also, what about property $$P(G) = \text{ this graph is isomorphic to graph } G_0$$ for some predefined graph $G_0$? Or perhaps something even stronger, like "is isomorphic to some graph in family $\mathcal{G}_0$".

Comment: Check this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aanderaa%E2%80%93Karp%E2%80%93Rosenberg_conjecture

Comment: @dtldarek : Both properties you mentioned are valid graph properties. But first one is not monotone, since adding edges can destroy the property.
In 2nd case, it depends on characterisation of the family.

Comment: I was under the impression that you asked precisely about the _non_-monotone properties, is that right?

Comment: I asked about non monotone properties which are evasive. The property which you gave doesn't seem to be evasive(it actually depends on $G_0$)

Comment: I think that there are graphs that would work for $G_0$ or families for $\mathcal{G}_0$, but to make it simpler, what about "$G$ is empty or $G$ is a clique" or its complement "$G$ is non-empty and not a clique". Both are non-monotone and evasive.

Comment: The property that a graph is empty is decreasingly monotonic, and property that graph is clique is increasingly monotonic. So again this is not the example I sought.

Comment: Also the property that graph has exactly k edges, is intersection of graph has "atleast k edges" and "atmost k edges". both of which are increasingly and decreasingly monotonic respectively.

Comment: Maybe those are monotonic by themselves, but their sum isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property "has an even number of edges" is non-monotonic and evasive.

EDIT: 
While the asker's original question was about non-monotone graph properties, it appears his interest has further extended to exclude properties which are unions of intersections of monotone graph properties. Unfortunately for the asker, every graph property can be formulated as the union of the intersection of monotone graph properties.

Let $P$ be a graph property (considered as a set of graphs). Let $P = \cup_k P_k$ where $P_k$ is the set of graphs in $P$ containing exactly $k$ edges. Let $A_k$ denote the set of graphs $G$ with $\leq k$ edges such that $G$ can be extended to a graph $H \in P_k$ via the addition of zero or more edges. Similarly, let $B_k$ be the set of graphs $G$ with $\geq k$ edges such that a graph $H \in P_k$ can be obtained from $G$ via the deletion of zero or more edges in $G$. By construction, $A_k$ and $B_k$ are monotone and $P_k = A_k \cap B_k$. Hence $P$ is the union of the intersection of monotone properties.

Comment: Since a graph is finite, this is a finite union of "Does the graph have k edges?" for all even k. where each term is an intersection of "atleast k" and "atmost k".

So again, it was possible to break it down to monotone properties.
Is it always possible then?

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular formulation of monotonicity. Is this standard? I'm having trouble thinking of any property that can't be broken down to some intersection of monotone properties by this definition. Can you provide an example of a graph property that does not break down this way?

Comment: "Whether a graph is a scorpion?".
http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbaswana/Puzzles/Algo/Figures/scorpion.gif
the n-3 vertices in feet can be connected in any way among each other, but the body, tail and sting always remain as in this image.
Note: this graph was used in 1974 to disprove Rosenberg's original conjecture.

Comment: I haven't worked out all the details here, but can the graph property "is a scorpion" be considered the intersection of the monotone properties "contains a scorpion" and "is contained in a scorpion"?

Comment: In my opinion we cannot consider this, since "is contained in a scorpion?" is a trivially true, because the feet and the body vertex can be a clique(complete graph).
Thus any graph of n vertices is contained in a scorpion of n+2 of more vertices.
The AKR conjecture **only** deals with non-trivial graph properties.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. By "is contained in a scorpion", I meant "edges can be added to make this graph a scorpion". Or equivalently, "is contained in a scorpion with the same number of vertices". (Similarly, for "contains a scorpion" => "edges can be removed to make this graph a scorpion")

Comment: Please see my edited answer for a further generalization of this principle.

Comment: The proof which you gave is incorrect. Because, for example if graph property is P = "graph is a forest" .Now when you take some P_k (denoting exactly k edges), it will even contain a cycle of k edges. Hence P_k is not simply graph containing k edges, but it should also be also satisfying P itself. Hence this is not a correct way to break up every graph property.

Comment: However, the fact that we can break up graph properties into monotone graph properties seems to be correct. For example there is another non-evasive property: "Graph has a sink".
Here a sink in a directed graph of n vertices is a vertex with in-degree n-1 and out degree 0.
Now this can be simply broken into "has a vertex with out degree 0"(decreasing monotone) and "has a vertex with in-degree n-1"(increasing monotone), when we take intersection, both these properties will always refer to the same vertex which will be the sink.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your objection. $P_k$ is not defined as the set of all graphs containing $k$ edges; it is the subset of $P$ consisting of graphs containing $k$ edges.